# Как кешировать ajax запросы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Понимаю что много подобных вопросов, но мало внятных ответов.
Есть подобие чата, сообщения в котором обновляются каждые 100 милисекунд, естественно в чатике есть и фото и различные файлы, а это серьёзный ddos сервера,  1. Как постоянно не перезаписать сообщения на сайте, 2. Как понизить нагрузку с регулярной передачей инфы... Как я это представляю: человек пишет сообщение, оно добавляется в конце и кешируется, сервер повторно отправляет запрос, если ничего в кеше не изменилось, тогда выводим кеш...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### как написать чатик?

https://socket.io/ в помощь
всё очень просто: на клиенте

```
const socket = io();
const addText = text => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', text)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        addText(msg)
    });
});
```

подробное руководство там 
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: Хотелось бы без сокетов, по принципу вк.. Они юзают polling с кешированием вроде

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев, 1) (с кешированием) я в упор не понимаю что вы собираетесь кэшировать, бэк/фронт, если фронт - всё уже в доме, для чего кэш? пришло сообщение - отправилось в дом. всё. если нужен поиск или что ещё - это отдельная тема, пока так покрутите

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев, 2) предложенная мной библиотека использует то, что есть, что поддерживается, тоесть если сокеты не поддерживаются она задействует другой механизм (возможно и polling, врать не буду )

Comment: Нашёл вариант на лонг пул http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/111253/blog941.html

Comment: Но он перестаёт работать через несколько минут afk

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев,1) ваш вопрос нужно раздилить на два: front / back 2)вы уверены, что сейчас вам важнее разработка бэкэнда?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ один - перестаньте думать про велосипеды.

Если быть точнее - если вы не хотите прослыть динозавром среди коллег, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на какой ни-будь framework. Ну, например, Vue.js - чтоб понять суть. Ну или Angular, что немного сложней. Заодно и typescript узнаете. Он вам понравится :)
Более того, когда начнете искать работу, то предпочтение отдадут не велосепидисту, который говнокодит, а вам ибо вы , то что называется, в тренде. :)

Comment: Вы предлагаете, людям которые только осваивают язык, его возможности и как он работает, не быть "динозаврами" и  начать изучать фреймворк. Как на меня это чушь. Так как без основ и понимания языка, вам фреймворки не нужны.

Comment: Да. Именно это я и предлагаю. Более того, я считаю единственным правильным путем изучать любой язык - пользоваться сразу фреймворками. 
Хочу оговориться - не единственным конечно, это я загнул, однако основываясь на своем опыте именно это я и предлагаю. Хотя я уже написал это.  :)

Comment: @zalex, дайте перефразирую, вы предлагаете эту строчку `const addText = text => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', text)` заменить фреймворком

Comment: Нет. Давайте фантазировать ! Я предлагаю поменять подход к обучению любого языка методом отмены говнокода, но методом программирования, тем более что инструментов сейчас создано более чем достаточно. Сидеть и ковырять свои велосипеды - тратить напрасно время. Все равно придешь к тому, что сейчас популярно. 
Ну, или так. Попробуйте оспорить утверждение что человек, будучи в чужой языковой среде научится языку быстрее чем тот, кто учит язык по книгам.

Comment: @qwabra но что мне особо доставляет в вашем ответе, так это то, что вы предлагаете уважаемому автору использовать `cons socket = io();`  :) При этом одновременно рассказывая ему про важность понимания основ языка. Вы не улавливаете противоречия в своих словах ? Я улавливаю. Фреймворк, любой, автора вопроса переместит непосредственно в разработку, более того в определенные рамки. Хватит говнокода а просторах интернета, пока уже и за ум браться.
С уважением ! :)

Comment: @zalex, будьте внимательнее к нику собеседника. (При этом одновременно рассказывая ему про важность понимания основ языка)

Comment: @qwabra иди в жопу, друг.

Comment: Ребятки, хотелось без сокетов) (серверная часть на пыхе, старомодно, но...)